# Adding s in imperatif

Tags: prononciation, verbes, impératif

I learned that we add s to make the sentence sound better. Like:

> Va**s**-y
>
> Mange**s**-en

I noticed that whenever the verb ends with a vowel, and I'm using a pronoun that starts with a vowel, it adds the "s".

> Do I still add "s" when it is not a pronoun?
>
> Dites à votre amie d'aller en classe tous les jours. -> Va**s** en classe tous les jours!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add the `-s` only when the imperative is followed by a pronoun that starts with a vowel (which means *y* or *en*). Add `-s` only when the pronoun is a complement of the verb, not when it's the beginning of a longer expression that happens to follow the verb. There's always a hyphen after the `s`.

> Vas-y.
>   Va en classe.   (*en*)
>   Va en parler avec lui.   (*en* is a complement of *parler*)
>   Vas-y (pour) voir ce qui s'y passe.   (“Go now and see what is happening there” — *y* is a complement of *voir*)
>   Va y voir ce qui s'y passe.   (“Go there to see what is happening there” — *y* is a complement of *voir*)

For natives, the rule is “add an `-s` if it there's a [z] sound”, which obviously only helps if you speak French fluently and are learning to spell it. Even so, natives sometimes get this wrong. There's no `s` at the end of the imperative singular for first group (`-er` infinitive) verbs because it's derived from a [Latin ending](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_conjugation#Present_imperative) which was just a (long) vowel, but there's an `s` at the end of the corresponding indicative form which derives from a Latin `-s` ending. I suspect that in a few centuries, the imperative singular will align with the indicative (this has already happened with `-ir` and `-re` verbs). In the meantime, “no `-s` except before complement pronouns that start with a vowel” is a rule that natives do mostly follow in spoken language, even if they'd occasionally misspell it.

Comment: "Va y voir ce qui s'y passe" ? Ne doit-on pas plutôt dire "Va voir ce qui s'y passe" ? ou "Vas-y voir ce qui se passe" ?

Comment: @jcm69 “Vas-y voir ce qui se passe” is also possible. It has a different meaning: “Vas-y” is “go away now”, where as “Va y voir …” means “go there and see …”.

Comment: @Giiles Cette phrase avec deux *y* me semble un tantinet improbable. Mais pourquoi pas...